# how to resolve Bad configuration option: ^x^xxx6?

Tags: command-line, server, virtualbox, ssh

I created in a new user in my linux virtual machine in Windows 10 OS.

And I needed to connect to this new user.  I ran the following command and got the error.

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ ssh student@127.0.0.1 -p 2222
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 1: Bad configuration option: ^x^xxx6
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options

vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ ssh student@127.0.0.1 -p 22
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 1: Bad configuration option: ^x^xxx6
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
```

Comment: Did you edit the file /etc/ssh/ssh_config? Normally you wouldn't have to.

Comment: I did an attempt to change the port to 222 something like that, per this stackoverflow suggestion: https://askubuntu.com/questions/673597/ssh-connect-to-host-127-0-0-1-port-2222-connection-refused